# Difference between $R[c_1,c_2,\dots, c_n]$ and a finitely generated $R$-algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What is the difference between $R[c_1,c_2,\dots, c_n]$ ($c_1, c_2,\dots, c_n\notin R$), where $R$ is a ring, and a finitely generated $R$-algebra?

Is the difference that if $c_1, c_2,\dots, c_n$ are the generators of the $R$-algebra, then their highest powers are bounded in the $R$-algebra, while they are not in $R[c_1,c_2,\dots, c_n]$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $R[c_1,\dots,c_n]$ to mean a suitable quotient of the polynomial ring in $n$ variables? In that case, any finitely generated $R$-algebra will be isomorphic to such a ring, but writing it like this, we have also specified a set of generators which may be convenient.

Comment: Actually, what I said is not quite true, unless you assume the structure map to be injective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write the expression
$$R[c_1,\ldots,c_n],$$
what that signifies (to me at least) is a quotient of a polynomial ring $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$  by some ideal $I\subset R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ such that the composition of the maps
$$R\longrightarrow R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\longrightarrow R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$$
is injective; the $c_i$'s denote the equivalence classes of the $x_i$'s in the quotient ring.

Any such ring certainly a finitely-generated $R$-algebra, but the converse is not true. For example, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a finitely-generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, but it cannot be expressed as $\mathbb{Z}[c_1,\ldots,c_n]$ for any $c_i$'s in the manner described above.

If, however, you do ***not*** require the above map to be injective, then any finitely-generated $R$-algebra can be expressed as $R[c_1,\ldots,c_n]$, and any $R$-algebra $R[c_1,\ldots,c_n]$ is finitely-generated (both directions essentially by definition).

By the way, you seem confused about what it means for an $R$-algebra to be finitely generated. The polynomial ring $R[x]$ is an $R$-algebra, the powers of $x$ occurring in the elements of $R[x]$ are not bounded, and $x$ is a generator of $R[x]$ as an $R$-algebra.

Comment: @YACP I am curious to know what definition you might be using that would not allow that (it is clearly a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, and it is clearly finitely generated, even as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, not just as an algebra).

Comment: @YACP, an $R$-algebra (with $R$ commutative) is in many contexts defined simply as a ring $A$ together with a map $R\to A$ with central image.

Comment: @YACP: Given a ring $A$ and a ring homomorphism $f:R\to A$ (in other words: given an $R$-algebra $A$), if there exists a finite set $\{c_1,\ldots,c_n\}\subseteq A$ such that the unique $R$-algebra homomorphism $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\to A$ sending $x_i\mapsto c_i$ is surjective, then $A$ is finitely generated. In the case of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, literally **any** subset will do (even the empty set). As a general rule, I think something whose underlying set is finite had better be finitely-generated for any reasonable definition of finitely-generated.

Comment: +1 Great answer Zev! (If you saw the rest of this comment, then please ignore it (I've deleted it now); I was just momentarily confused!) Thank you for your reply; I saw that and I agree.

Comment: +1 I think from the beginning this answer was rather good, but then further explanations came and made it even more complete.

Comment: *In my opinion none of these comments made it clear what a finitely generated algebra is*. Dear @TobiasKildetoft, as far as I know since I was a student $A$ is an $R$-algebra ($R$ commutative) if there is a homomorphism $f:R\to A$ such that the image of $f$ is contained in the center of $A$. Now I call $A$ finitely generated over $R$ if $A$ is generated by $f(R)$ and a finite set of elements from $A$. **Now** it's obvious that $\mathbb Z_n$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-algebra.

Comment: @YACP: I think Tobias, Mariano, and I all assumed you were actually confused as to whether or not $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ was a finitely-generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra. Now I don't understand your purpose in asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about $R[c_1,\dots,c_n]$ *for $c_1,\dots,c_n\not\in R$*, then surely the $c_i$'s must live somewhere (don't we all?). So, perhaps you've got a **ring extension** $R\subseteq S$; here, $R$ is a subring of $S$. Also, $c_1,\dots,c_n\in S$ (but they aren't elements of $R$ by your assumption).

In this case, $R[c_1,\dots,c_n]=\{p(c_1,\dots,c_n):p\in R[x_1,\dots,x_n]\}$ is a **subring** of $S$. So, we have a triple $R\subseteq R[c_1,\dots,c_n]\subseteq S$ of rings. What is the structure of the ring $R[c_1,\dots,c_n]$? Maybe you don't care as long as it's a subring of $S$. But if you do care, then thankfully Zev has explained this point very nicely above. We have a surjective homomorphism of $R$-algebras $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to R[c_1,\dots,c_n]$ obtained by **evaluation at $(c_1,\dots,c_n)$**, i.e., $p(x_1,\dots,x_n)\to p(c_1,\dots,c_n)$. If you check this is indeed a surjective homomorphism of $R$-algebras, then Zev explains the rest! The ring $R[c_1,\dots,c_n]$ is isomorphic to a quotient ring of $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$! Here's an easy exercise in case you're interested:

***Exercise 1***: Prove that $R[c_1,\dots,c_n]$ is isomorphic to $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ as $R$-algebras if and only if the set $\{c_1,\dots,c_n\}$ is **algebraically independent over $R$** (meaning: there is no polynomial in $n$ variables with coefficients in $R$ that vanishes at the tuple $(c_1,\dots,c_n)$).

I hope this helps!

Comment: +1, thanks for catching Ayush's confusion in saying "$c_i\notin R$".

Comment: Thanks @Zev, I think our answers complement each other rather well!